# Связь между голосами и очередью проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок, голосование

После того, как был достигнут суточный лимит в сорок голосов,
перестало предлагать проверку Первых сообщений...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какая связь между одним и вторым? Это баг или фича? ))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Свободный перевод [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149669/339911) с MSE.

Очереди проверок "Первые сообщения" и "Запозданые ответы" позволяют не только выполнять необходимые правки, но также голосовать за или против на вопросах или ответах. Если суточный лимит голосов достигнут, то полноценно выполнять проверку в этих очередях не получится.

Очереди "Сообщения низкого качества", "Предлагаемые правки" и "Вопросы на закрытие" не требуют и не позволяют голосовать на сообщениях, поэтому данные очереди остаются доступны.